# Background-image making site scroll very slowly?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a static website, and for some reason the background-image is making the site scroll tremendously slow; it speeds up as soon as I remove the background image.

I wanted to use a CSS filter blur effect on the background, but you can't blur the background-image of the body, so this is what I did:

The HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="img/iphone.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#bg {
 position: fixed; 
 top: -50%; 
 left: -50%; 
 width: 200%; 
 height: 200%;
}

#bg img {
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 right: 0; 
 bottom: 0; 
 opacity:0.6;
 margin: auto; 
 min-width: 50%;
 min-height: 50%;
 filter: blur(3px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
 -moz-filter: blur(3px);
 -o-filter: blur(3px);
 -ms-filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Is there anything I can do to get the background-image blur effect I want but not destroy scroll speed?

Comment: Why not just blur the image in an editing program and use that as the background?

Comment: I'm not familiar with many photo editing programs. Do you know any free options to get this done on Windows? GIMP, maybe?

Comment: GIMP, PhotoFiltre - both are free and powerful. What size (Kb) is the image? Maybe some compression would do the trick.

Comment: Paint.NET is another good open source editor that could do it.

Comment: could i know why you delete your last question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555678/background-image-doesnt-stretch-whole-page its really bad it has answer ..